# How to handle a ActionEvent from another class

Tags: java, javafx, actionevent

I'm using JavaFX and working on a Schoolproject right now.

About my program, i have a login screen and if i press on login, i come to the mainframe. The content area of the mainframe is empty, because i load the content for the AnchorPane that builds the mainframe when i use the buttons in the menubar.

When i press the login button, i want to laod the mainframe and the home pane in it. But i don't know how to load the pane into the mainframe from another class.

Here my code:

Code to load the mainframe:

```
@FXML
protected void login(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Stage stage;
    Parent root = null;
    stage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
    try{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/mainframe.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 900);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();       

}
```

Code to laod the home pane into the mainframe:

```
@FXML
protected void mHome(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    try {                    
        URL url = getClass().getResource("view/home.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(url);
        fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load(url.openStream()); 

        aContent.getChildren().clear();
        aContent.getChildren().add(page);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

These two methods are in different classes.

If you need some more information, please let me know :)

Thank you and greets, Timo

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke the `mHome()` method. Note that, since you never use the `ActionEvent`, you can omit it from the method signature (the `FXMLLoader` will still be able to map it as an event handler). So change it to

```
@FXML
protected void mHome() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    try {                    
        URL url = getClass().getResource("view/home.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(url);
        fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load(url.openStream()); 

        aContent.getChildren().clear();
        aContent.getChildren().add(page);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If you *always* want to show the "home pane" when the main pane is first shown, just add a call to `mHome` to the `initialize()` method in the same controller class:

```
public void initialize() {
    // existing code...

    mHome();
}
```

Alternatively, if you specifically only want to show the "home pane" when you load it from the login pane, add a call to `mHome` in your login handler:

```
@FXML
protected void login(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Stage stage;
    Parent root = null;
    stage = (Stage) btnLogin.getScene().getWindow();
    try{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view/mainframe.fxml"));
        root = loader.load();
        MainController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.mHome();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1280, 900);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();       

}
```

(I'm assuming `MainController` is the name of the controller class for `mainframe.fxml`; obviously just adjust as needed.)

Comment: OK, i tried it and it works. The problem now is that i have implemented this into the code:

'aContent.getChildren().clear();
aContent.getChildren().add(page);'

That clears the AnchorPane aContent before i add a new fxml onto the Pane. But right now it is empty so it cant clear it and gives me an error...